# PHP: Return Array of Values from Key in Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, associative-array

Let's say that I have an array like this:

```
$people = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Bob',
        'job'  => 'Carpenter'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'George',
        'job'  => 'Programmer'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Clint',
        'job'  => 'Actor'
    )
);
```

And I want to know the names of all of these people.

I know that I could do this:

```
$names = array();

foreach($people as $person)
    $names[] = $person['name'];
```

But let's say that I'm lazy, so I create a function for it instead:

```
/**
 * Returns an Array of Values paired with the specified $key
 * in the $array of Associative Arras.
 *
 * @param array  $array The Array of Associative Arrays.
 * @param string $key   The Key within each Associative Array to retrieve the Value
 *
 * @return array The Array of Keyed Values within the Array of Arrays.
 */
function array_keyed_values($array, $key)
{
    $values = array();

    foreach($array as $associative)
        if(array_key_exists($key, $associative))
            $values[] = $associative[$key];

    return $values;
}
```

Cool, I've officially solved my problem. I just need to do:

```
$names = array_keyed_values($people, 'name');
```

To get:

```
(Bob, George, Clint)
```

And I'm done.

However, I doubt that I'm the first person to need this kind of functionality. Given that PHP is littered with a plethora of quirky functions that do weird things, I'm wondering if something like this already exists.

Yes, I know, I'm only saving myself 10 to 20 lines of code by not writing the function I need, but in a framework that uses tons of files, having to constantly include a library to do something this simple tends to get a little tedious.

I've tried searching around for this, but I might not be using the right keywords. Something like this involves arrays, keys, and values, so searching for that type of stuff tends to constantly point me to [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) or [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), neither of which is what I want.

**NOTE:**

For the particular application I'm using, the ordering of the values when returned does *not* matter.

Also, the version of PHP I'm using is 5.3. If a later version of PHP adds this functionality, please state that in your answer.

**EDIT:**

The following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200794/php-return-array-of-values-from-key-in-associative-array/30200818#30200818) worked in this scenario:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return $v['name']; }, $people);
```

However, I also used this to solve a similar problem where I had an array of objects *(where the nested arrays where the objects, and the keys were the variables)*. By slightly modifying the code above, I solved that problem too:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return $v->name; }, $people);
```

While [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) works for my scenario *(if I were using PHP 5.5+ instead of PHP 5.3)*, it wouldn't work for the modified solution above *(Hence the edit)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$result = array_column($people, 'name');
```

Older versions >= 5.3.0:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return $v['name']; }, $people);
```

For even older just use `array_map` with a concrete function.

Comment: Older versions just means: >= 5.3 :)

Comment: Yes, edited.....  Anything older than 5.3.0 and you have more problems.  It's 6 years old.

Comment: yeah, then you would have to pass the function name as string or use `create_function()` which wouldn't be the best solution

Comment: Really?  What would be then?  `foreach`?  Already in OP.